# How to query by date in REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using loopback to generate REST API and having an Attendance table which contain the attendance record of students. Following query gives me the result as given below.

> http://localhost:3000/api/attendances?filter[where][date]=2015-08-27T05:26:33.000Z

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "regno": "1414",
    "name": "Salman",
    "reason": "on leave",
    "class": "R",
    "date": "2015-08-27T05:26:33.000Z",
    "status": true,
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

but I want to get the same result by querying like that

> http://localhost:3000/api/attendances?filter[where][date]=2015-08-27

i.e Time should not be necessory.. or consider it an unknown entity. How can I get the same result as above ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently loopback doesn't have support for something like that. Feel free to open an issue, but this works for me with postgresql:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/Attendances?filter[where][start][between][0]=2015-08-29&filter[where][start][between][1]=2015-08-29T23:59:59.999Z
```

You can also override the find method to do this for you.

```
var originalFind = Attendance.find;
Attendance.find = function(filter) {
    if (filter && filter.where && filter.where.date) {
       // check if the date and convert the filter if needed.
    }
    return originalFind.apply(this, arguments);
};
```